# MSI P67A-GD65 B3 + Realtek ALC892 not working in windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard

I had sound working right after I installed Windows XP at one point. I am not sure if it was "high def" or not, because i only had a simple set of headphones plugged in. Apparently some update or something has caused my sound to not work completely.

What can I do to get this working?

I have tried the WDM_258 driver or whatever from Realtek's website, and I have tried deleting everything from device manager that had to do with Realtek, and reinstalling from the CD that came with the motherboard. Nothing seems to be working.

I know the card works, because this system dual boots to Ubuntu, and I have sound there! Windows keeps popping up telling me it finds a "high def audio device" or something, but when I try to install, it says it cant find the necessary drivers, even though I have pointed it to the stuff I have downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver I found on the MSI site seems to be named realtek_hd_mb_all.zip ...you got that one yet? Here's the link for XP 32 bit.
http://msi.com/service/download/driver-2584.html

Unless msi screwed up their own page, this definitely should contain the correct driver. Probably it has several (108 megs zipped, sheesh) and you'll have to be careful pointing it to the right one. Try a couple within this package to be sure, it's not impossible one got placed in the wrong folder within that zip.